# Could someone please just tell me why my for() loop will not count all the way up?

Tags: c++

I read in from the command line arguments and they are as follows:

```
0.5 3 10 50
```

The maxClock is the last argument, which is 50 in this case. I then have a for loop that goes as such:

```
for(int k = 1; k < maxClock; k++)
{
    <code>
}
```

But for whatever reason, my program will not count up to k. Sometimes it will only count up to 9, then 34, then 14, etc... I have no clue what is going on. Could someone please give me an alternate view?

Here is the code:

/*
     * Driver.cpp

```
 *
 * This program simulates a bank with customers walking in for service and seeing tellers.
 * This program implements a classic Queue style system.
 *
 * Disclaimer:
 *
 *  - For some reason, the program will not run up until the time maxClock given in the command line arguments.
 *    This prevents the program from being able to print out the averageQueue length, maxQueueLength, etc at the
 *    bottom right after the for-loop.
 *
 *
 *
 */



////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
///Includes///
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdlib>
#include "Queue.h"
#include "Customer.h"
#include "QueueNode.h"
#include "Teller.h"

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    srand(time(NULL)); //seeds the random time generator

    if(argc != 5)
    {
        cout << "You must enter at least 5 command line arguments " << endl;
        exit(1);
    }

    /******************Command Line Args-Variables***************************/
    double p = atof(argv[1]);
    int numTellers = atoi(argv[2]); //number of the tellers (M)
    int maxService = atoi(argv[3]);
    int maxClock = atoi(argv[4]); //simulation time (N)

    /******************Local Variables***************************/
    int numberOfCustomers = 0;
    int serv;
    int randProb;
    int totalWait;
    unsigned long long AverageWaitTime;
    int customerWillBeFinished;
    int maxQLength;
    int counter;
    int AverageQueueLength;
    int wait;
    int individualWaitTime;
    int OtherThanK;
    int a = 10000;

    //Displays to user to double checks to make sure you entered in the arguments correctly
    cout << "------------------------------------------------------------" << endl;
    cout << "These are the arguments that you gave the program: " << endl;
    cout << endl;
    cout << "The p value is: " << p << endl;
    cout << "The number of tellers: " << numTellers << endl;
    cout << "The max service time is: " << maxService << endl;
    cout << "The max clock is: " << maxClock << endl;
    cout << endl;
    cout << "------------------------------------------------------------" << endl;
    cout << "\n";

    /******************Declaration of Queue & Vector***************************/
    Queue<Customer> line;
    vector<Teller> teller(numTellers);

    //loop to go through entire clock until the maxClock is reached
    for(int k = 1; k < maxClock; k++)
    {
        OtherThanK = k;
        randProb = ((rand() % 100) + 1); //generates a random number seeded with system time
        if(randProb < p*100)
        {
                serv = ((rand() % maxService) + 1); //generates a random number seeded with system time
                Customer customer(OtherThanK, serv); //passes in current time and service time (randomizeD)
                line.enqueue(customer); //pushes a customer onto the Queue.
                cout << "Customer arriving in queue at time: " << OtherThanK << endl;
        }
        customerWillBeFinished = serv + OtherThanK + 1;
        for(int i = 0; i < numTellers; i++)
        {
            if(teller[i].isFree() && (!line.isempty())) //checks to see if a teller is empty
            {
                cout << "Teller " << i << " is now free." << endl;
                Customer frontCustomer; //declares a customer called frontCustomer. This is the customer who is at the front of the Queue.
                line.dequeue(frontCustomer); //pulls off a customer from the Queue.
                wait = OtherThanK - frontCustomer.getArrivalTime();
                numberOfCustomers++; //increases by 1 each time through to keep tracking of the # of Customers.
                totalWait = totalWait + wait;
                cout << "Customer going to teller " << i << " at time " << frontCustomer.getArrivalTime() << endl; //retrieves arrival time
                cout << "This customer had to wait in line for " << wait << " minutes." << endl; //labs() is a function used to determine absolute value
                cout << "This customer will require " << serv << " minutes of service" << endl;
                teller[i].addCustomer(frontCustomer);
                line.remove(frontCustomer); //once cycled through, removes the customer from the Queue.

            }
        }
        cout << endl;
        cout << "Time is: "<< k << endl;
        cout << " \n Number of customers: " << numberOfCustomers << " " << "Total wait so far: " << std::labs(totalWait) << endl; //labs() is a function used to determine absolute value
    }

///////// WON'T PRINT ANY OF THIS OUT BECAUSE IT WONT EXIT LOOP ///////
    cout << "test" <<endl;
    AverageWaitTime = totalWait/numberOfCustomers;
    cout << "Average wait time is: " << AverageWaitTime*a << endl;
    maxQLength = line.getLength();
    cout << "The max Queue length is " << maxQLength << endl;
    AverageQueueLength = maxQLength/OtherThanK;
    cout << "The Average Queue Length is " << AverageQueueLength;
}
```

Output example: (changes every time, this particular time it counted up to 20):

```
------------------------------------------------------------
These are the arguments that you gave the program: 

The p value is: 0.5
The number of tellers: 3
The max service time is: 10
The max clock is: 50

------------------------------------------------------------

Max Clock is 50

Time is: 0

 Number of customers: 0 Total wait so far: 0
Max Clock is 50

Time is: 1

 Number of customers: 0 Total wait so far: 0
Max Clock is 50
Customer arriving in queue at time: 2
Teller 0 is now free.
Customer going to teller 0 at time 2
This customer had to wait in line for 0 minutes.
This customer will require 4 minutes of service

Time is: 2

 Number of customers: 1 Total wait so far: 0
Max Clock is 50
Customer arriving in queue at time: 3
Teller 1 is now free.
Customer going to teller 1 at time 3
This customer had to wait in line for 0 minutes.
This customer will require 10 minutes of service

Time is: 3

 Number of customers: 2 Total wait so far: 0
Max Clock is 50

Time is: 4

 Number of customers: 2 Total wait so far: 0
Max Clock is 50
Customer arriving in queue at time: 5
Teller 2 is now free.
Customer going to teller 2 at time 5
This customer had to wait in line for 0 minutes.
This customer will require 7 minutes of service

Time is: 5

 Number of customers: 3 Total wait so far: 0
Max Clock is 50
Customer arriving in queue at time: 6
Teller 0 is now free.
Customer going to teller 0 at time 6
This customer had to wait in line for 0 minutes.
This customer will require 2 minutes of service

Time is: 6

 Number of customers: 4 Total wait so far: 0
Max Clock is 50

Time is: 7

 Number of customers: 4 Total wait so far: 0
Max Clock is 50

Time is: 8

 Number of customers: 4 Total wait so far: 0
Max Clock is 50

Time is: 9

 Number of customers: 4 Total wait so far: 0
Max Clock is 50

Time is: 10

 Number of customers: 4 Total wait so far: 0
Max Clock is 50
Customer arriving in queue at time: 11
Teller 0 is now free.
Customer going to teller 0 at time 11
This customer had to wait in line for 0 minutes.
This customer will require 8 minutes of service

Time is: 11

 Number of customers: 5 Total wait so far: 0
Max Clock is 50
Customer arriving in queue at time: 12
Teller 2 is now free.
Customer going to teller 2 at time 12
This customer had to wait in line for 0 minutes.
This customer will require 5 minutes of service

Time is: 12

 Number of customers: 6 Total wait so far: 0
Max Clock is 50

Time is: 13

 Number of customers: 6 Total wait so far: 0
Max Clock is 50

Time is: 14

 Number of customers: 6 Total wait so far: 0
Max Clock is 50
Customer arriving in queue at time: 15
Teller 1 is now free.
Customer going to teller 1 at time 15
This customer had to wait in line for 0 minutes.
This customer will require 10 minutes of service

Time is: 15

 Number of customers: 7 Total wait so far: 0
Max Clock is 50
Customer arriving in queue at time: 16

Time is: 16

 Number of customers: 7 Total wait so far: 0
Max Clock is 50
Customer arriving in queue at time: 17
Teller 2 is now free.
Customer going to teller 2 at time 16
This customer had to wait in line for 1 minutes.
This customer will require 2 minutes of service

Time is: 17

 Number of customers: 8 Total wait so far: 1
Max Clock is 50

Time is: 18

 Number of customers: 8 Total wait so far: 1
Max Clock is 50

Time is: 19

 Number of customers: 8 Total wait so far: 1
Max Clock is 50

Time is: 20

 Number of customers: 8 Total wait so far: 1
Max Clock is 50
Customer arriving in queue at time: 21
Teller 0 is now free.
Customer going to teller 0 at time 21
This customer had to wait in line for 0 minutes.
This customer will require 10 minutes of service
```

Customer.h Class:

```
/*
 * Customer.h
 *
 */

#ifndef CUSTOMER_H_
#define CUSTOMER_H_

#include <iostream>
#include "QueueNode.h"
#include "Queue.h"
#include "Teller.h"
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

class Customer
{

public:
    int serviceTime;
    int arrivalTime;
    Customer()
    {
        serviceTime = 0;
        arrivalTime = 0;
    }

    Customer(int arrival, int maxService)
    {
        arrivalTime = arrival;
        serviceTime = maxService;
    }

    int getServiceTime()
    {
        return serviceTime;
    }
    bool isDone()
    {
        serviceTime--;
        return serviceTime <= 0;
    }

    int getArrivalTime()
    {
        return arrivalTime;
    }
    void MinutePasses()
    {
        serviceTime--;
    }
};

#endif /* CUSTOMER_H_ */
```

Teller.h Class:

```
/*
 * 
 */

#ifndef TELLER_H_
#define TELLER_H_

#include <iostream>
#include "Customer.h"
#include "QueueNode.h"
#include "Queue.h"

using namespace std;

class Teller
{
private:
    //bool isOccupied;
    Customer customer;
protected:
    bool free;
public:
    Teller()
    {
        //isOccupied = false;
        free = true;
    }
    bool isFree()
    {
        //return free; - > B C
        if(!free)
        {
            customer.serviceTime--;
            if(customer.serviceTime == 0)
            {
                free = true;
                return true;
            }
            else return false;
        }
        {
            return true;
        }


    }

    void addCustomer(Customer C)
    {
        customer = C;
        free = false;
    }
    void CustMinutePasses()
    {
        if(!free)
        {
            customer.MinutePasses();
        }
    }
    Customer & getCustomer()
    {
        return customer;
    }
    void setAvailability(bool b)
    {
        free = b;
    }
    /*
    void setAvailability(bool b)
    {
        free = b;
    }
    */
};



#endif /* TELLER_H_ */
```

Comment: Can you attach the output? I'm stumped.

Comment: Does your program exit?  If not, then you need to step through the code in the debugger and look at k.

Comment: @DamienBlack I just edited the question to include output.

Comment: what does `teller[i].isFree()` do? Can we see the source?

Comment: the loop stucks somewhere in the middle, that's why it doesn't count till the end

Comment: What happens at the end? Is it just stuck or does it close?

Comment: Anything in addCustomer that could be getting hung up?

Comment: @DamienBlack the program just closes. It doesn't hang--just exists. mangusta, that's what I've figured but I don't see where it could possibly get stuck. k and maxClock aren't changing anywhere.

Comment: @user3330599 are you sure? but then where are averages supposed to be printed at the end ?

Comment: the loop should print `Time is: 21` but it can't, it stops somewhere here `teller[i].addCustomer(frontCustomer);line.remove(frontCustomer); `

Comment: I've also included the teller.h and customer.h classes.

Comment: I think you have some other code (perhaps in `teller[i].addCustomer(frontCustomer);` or `line.remove(frontCustomer);` or something else) going off into la-la land. You're going to have to do some debugging in those areas. I don't think staring at this part of the code is going to solve it.

Comment: You are including cstdlib first and then using free as a variable name - that sounds dangerous. I'm not saying it is causing the problem but change the variable free to isFree and see what happens

Comment: Try to produce a *minimal* but *complete* example to increase the attention of the question. 4 code blocks with scrollbars is not "minimal".

Answer (score 2):

The program should indeed run to maxclock-1 (!) unless it crashes (or hangs) because of an error. There are no additional conditions in the loop and you don't appear to change to the loop index or boundary.

It appeared to work when I ran it with a tweaked queue implementation which I found at http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/general/71229/.

Since you don't provide a queue implementation the queue could be a source of error.

One possible reason: I noticed that you dequeue **and then remove** frontCustomer. "My" queue implementation removed the first element from the queue as part of dequeuing. The original queue implementation I used didn't provide a remove(); since your method requires a parameter I assume that it would search the whole queue for that particular element, using a default operator==(). I don't know what your queue does when that element doesn't exist, especially if the queue is empty.

**@Damien Black:** Utterly wrong. Please fix your comment. You get dissed on comp.lang.c++ for it, cf. https://groups.google.com/d/msg/comp.lang.c++/3d9ts9JuA-Q/6PtGSoXSIHQJ

C++ passes by value unless the formal param is specified as reference in the function signature by prefixing it with the & symbol. You may be confusing the semantics with C#.

And while C# handles classes through references, these references are passed by value (!) unless you qualify the formal and actual parameter "ref".